# How can I assign a two dimensional array to a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to assign an array to a pointer so I can use it

```
int arrayA[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int arrayB[3][1] = {{1},{2},{3}};
int** arrayC;
if(case1)
   arrayC = arrayA;
if(case2)
   arrayC = arrayB;
//work with arrayC
```

What could I do?

**Edit: Found another solution. See Answers**

Comment: What is your actual problem? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: the two arrays have completely different dimensions. How would you "work with arrayC" if it has either 4 or 3 elements in total?

Comment: i would store the dimensions in another variable

Comment: the proper way would be to wrap the array in a class and provide a nice and clean interface for all operations you need. However, you dont have to reinvent the wheel, simply use `std::vector` (or `std::array` if appropriate) instead of plain arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with dynamic initialisation of the array:

```
int arrayA[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
int arrayB[3][1] = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };
int** arrayC;
int dimension1, dimension2;
if (case1)
{
    dimension1=2;
    dimension2=2;
    arrayC = new int*[dimension1];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension1; i++)
        arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
}
if (case2)
{
    dimension1=3;
    dimension2=1;       
    arrayC = new int*[dimension1];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension1; i++)
        arrayC[i] = arrayB[i];
}
//work with arrayC
for (int i=0; i<dimension1; i++)
   arrayC=null;
delete[] arrayC;
```

Answer (score 2):

`int **` is a fundamentally different and therefore incompatible data type than a 2D array `int [][]`.

The only simple way to do the kind of thing you are attempting in your example above is to flatten your 2D arrays to 1D arrays:

```
int arrayA[2 * 2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int arrayB[3 * 1] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int* arrayC;
if (case1)
   arrayC = arrayA;
if (case2)
   arrayC = arrayB;
```

Obviously you'll then need to do explicit array index calculations yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign (the correct term is convert) a 2D array to a pointer to pointer.   The reason is that the conversion of a 1D array to a pointer (to the first element) is not applicable in higher dimensions.

What you can do is declare a pointer to an array of two int.  The conversion in this case is valid.

```
int arrayA[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int   (*arrayB)[2];
arrayB = arrayA;
```

The thing to realise, though, is that `*arrayB` is the address of the first element of `arrayA`.   In this example, that element is the array initialised using `{1,2}`.

**Edited to add the following after the original question was edited to ask a different question.**

The above does require consistency of dimensions though, so will not work in your (now edited example) where dimensions don't match.   It is the last (right-most) dimension that needs to match.

If you want mismatch of dimensions, there is no solution other than flattening the array to a single dimension.